# MySQL query: start date but no end date

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a query for a database that pulls all records starting from today - 90 days and then anything forward from that. However, I realize that I've coded my query so it ONLY pulls a 90 day range. So I need to indicate the start date but then I don't need to indicate the end date, I want everything from the past 90 days going forward.

```
    SELECT project_id, project_name, project_end
    FROM projects
    WHERE project_end BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND SYSDATE()
    ORDER BY project_id ASC;
```

since this only returns projects with an end date of today -90 and nothing for future end dates. To further complicate matters, some projects don't have an end date entered at all (null values) and some have been entered with 0000-00-00.

What's the best way to indicate a range that starts 90 days ago and then goes forward with no specific end date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about using `>=`?

```
WHERE project_end >= SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY OR
      project_end IS NULL OR
      project_end = '0000-00-00'
```

Comment: Just doing project_end >= SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY is what I needed. I don't want it to return the null or 0000-00-00 values. (I will accept this as the answer as soon as I can). Thank you JW!

Answer (score 0):

Why you need an interval? I think you could use:

```
WHERE
  project_end >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY
  OR COALESCE(project_end, '0000-00-00') = '0000-00-00'
```

This will select all projects that have a project_end in the last 90 days, or have a NULL project end, or a project end = '0000-00-00'